# push is not a function, received on an Angular FormArray

Tags: angular, formarray

I'm following a YouTube video to learn Angular ([this one, around 2h 52m](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uYhAfgEwNWA)).
These courses are 4 years old (2018), and I'm attempting to apply them on an *Angular 12*.

Currently I have to add some controls to a `FormArray`, on a reactive form.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initForm();
  }

  initForm(): void {
    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', Validators.required, Validators.email],
      drinkPreference: ['', Validators.required],
      hobbies: [this.formBuilder.array([])]
    });
  }

  getHobbies(): FormArray {
    return this.userForm.get('hobbies') as FormArray;
  }

  onAddNewHobby(): void {
    const nouvelHobby: FormControl = this.formBuilder.control('', Validators.required);
    this.getHobbies().push(nouvelHobby);
  }
```

the `onAddNewHobby` method is the `(click)` target for a button.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="onAddNewHobby()">Ajouter un hobby</button>
```

But when I click on my button (that is inside divs, in an HTML page, etc.)

I am receiving an error:

> ERROR TypeError: this.getHobbies().push is not a function

But as far as I can see, everything should be working...

[image]

What am I in front of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In line:

```
hobbies: [this.formBuilder.array([])]
```

... remove brackets, like this:

```
hobbies: this.formBuilder.array([])
```

Comment: ok but just WHY?